# Not getting "can edit" option while sharing sharepoint online files

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions

Library has 6000+ Items.

Even the Owner or SCA of the site does not see "can edit" option while sharing the file using share option.

Other libraries work just fine. Even the same file if saved in another document library has both the options while sharing. Please help!!

[image: s]

Comment: You said "Other libraries work just fine", do you mean the libraries of same site?

Comment: Yes, in the same site

Answer (score 0):

Since other libraries of the same site work fine, it seems the global settings is fine.

The issue may result by lager number of items. When a list view shows more than 5000 items, you may run into a list view threshold error.

It is suggested to move some items to another library or create folder and move the documents in folder.

Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint online for your reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59